# Excel: Format conditional

Tags: excel, formatting

How to format cell using personal and plural case?
I need:
1 unidade or
2 unidades
3 unidades

Singular and plural in the format cell.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[=1]` to apply a condition & `;` to combine with an alternate format string;

```
 [=1]0 "unidade";0 "unidades"
```